# Display products against attributes in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am working on custom module in magento.

I create two new attributes (combo box) make and location. After that I add values for these attributes using custom code against specific product. Like I add make "Sony" and location is "Australia" against product 1 (1 is id for product).

Now on admin side i want to display this product with attributes values like make is Sony and location is Australia and product is 1.

I found some tables where these values are linked like (catalog_product_entity_int,eav_attribute,eav_attribute_option,eav_attribute_option_value), but I am unable to query such records. The page where I want to display data I have attribute id and attribute code.

Can anyone knows how I can figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple Dude.

inside your _prepareCollection() method of your custom module grid

Load the product collection and select these two attribute... If there is a need to filter it by these two attributes then do it.